# Understanding the difference between object.function(argument) and object:function(argument) in Lua

Tags: function, object, methods, lua, evaluation

```
obj ={x=30}

function obj:printpos()
  print(self.x)
end

other = {x=15}

obj.printpos(other)
```

The `obj.printpos(other)` gives expected output viz. `15`. However the call `obj:printpos(other)` doesn't give expected output.It still prints `30`. Why the call `obj:printpos(other)` is not taking `other` as its argument? Basically what is the difference between `object.function(argument)` and `object:function(argument)`? Is `object:function(argument)` same as `object:function()` i.e. whether argument is ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj:printpos(other)` is equivalent to `obj.printpos(obj, other)`.

`function obj:printpos() end` is equivalent to `function obj.printpos(self) end`.

Comment: Probably not exactly equivalent for global variables. Your example would get `_G.obj` twice, Lua will store the "self" object in a local variable when you do `obj:printpos(other)`.

So it's probably rather equivalent to `do local obj = obj; obj.printpos(obj, other) end`.

Answer (score 1):

From [*Lua 5.4 Reference Manual*](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html) - [§3.4.11 – Function Definitions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.11) (*formatting mine*):

> The colon syntax is used to emulate methods, adding an implicit extra parameter `self` to the function. Thus, the statement
>
> ```lua
> function t.a.b.c:f (params) body end
> ```
>
> is syntactic sugar for
>
> ```lua
> t.a.b.c.f = function (self, params) body end
> ```

From this, we can see the colon syntax implicitly adds the `self` parameter to the function scope.

Inversely, calling a function defined with the colon syntax *using* the dot syntax will cause the first argument passed to it to be assigned to the `self` parameter.

Thus, with

```lua
local thing = {}

function thing:func()
    print(self)
end
```

the calls

```lua
thing:func()
-- and
thing.func(thing)
```

have the same result of assigning `thing` to `self`, and

```lua
thing.func(other_thing)
```

will assign `other_thing` to `self`.

The problem with

```lua
thing:func(other_thing)
```

is that, as previously seen, `thing` is assigned to `self`. `other_thing` is assigned to no parameter, as no other parameters were defined.